# How can set encoding ascii in yaml.load()

Tags: python-2.7, pyyaml

I am trying to convert string to dictionary but I want to preserve my encoding but as soon as I do

```
data = yaml.load(data)
```

It converts it to utf encoding. Is there anyway to preserve my encoding in yaml.load module?

Answer (score 0):

Not unless your encoding is something that can be specified by a BOM. By default `yaml.load()` expects an 'utf-8' encoded string, if type `str` is passed in,  although a BOM can force it to support UTF-16. If no BOM is specified and the string contains only ASCII characters, then you get type `str` back, or else type `unicode`. If you have special characters you should hand them in as Unicode and then you get unicode back.

You should just decode from the format you have into unicode and then encode back:

```
# coding: cp850

import ruamel.yaml as yaml

copyright = '\xb8'

print(u'{!r} {}'.format(copyright, copyright.decode('cp850')) )
y = yaml.load(copyright.decode('cp850'))
print(u'{} {}'.format(type(y), repr(y.encode('cp850'))))
```

will give you

```
'\xb8' ©
<type 'unicode'> '\xb8'
```

If you do that often, just write a wrapper around `yaml.load()`.

I tested this with my enhanced version of PyYAML ([ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml)), but this should work the same in PyYAML itself.